# Cannot SSH to VPS After ifup?

Tags: centos, ssh, failover

I have a vps hosted by OVH with CentOS installed.  I purchased 9 failover IPs and configured them as `eth0:1-eth0:8`.  After I edited the config files to what was recommended by OVH as:

```
DEVICE="eth0:0"

BOOTPROTO="static"

IPADDR="IP.FAIL.OVER"

NETMASK="255.255.255.255"

ONBOOT="yes"

BROADCAST="IP.FAIL.OVER"
```

The machine hung up and kicked me out.  I restarted the vps via the control panel and now the machine isn't pingable, can't SSH to it, and the failover IPs aren't pingable either.

Any idea where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: I would place failover IPs in dummy interfaces. It depends on the solution, the need, and the setup of the infra-structure.